# How do I upgrade to FancyBox v3 from v2.x?

Tags: fancybox

About a month ago I purchased Fancyapps FancyBox-v2.1.0-0 on 20-09-2012 to use it on multiple domains. Now, version 3 has come out. How can I upgrade to it? Do I have to pay the full price again?

Comment: Why not contact the supplier?

Comment: `closed as not constructive` but up voted ;) ... first, there is not v3, the latest is v2.1.3, just download it (nothing more to pay) from [fancybox website](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license) and you are all set.